# Simple menu with typoscript

Tags: menu, typoscript

I am working on a typo3 website .. and the menu must be dynamically generated .. so it needs to be with typoscript generated . I mean the typoscript generates the html code and of course I have already my css style . I just need the typoscript code that generates this hierarchy

```
                 <div class="row">
                        <a href="kurse.html">
                            <div class="nav-item"> 
                                <img src="images/item-icon.jpg" class="nav-item-img">
                                kurse 
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="kraft.html">
                            <div class="nav-item"> 
                               <img src="images/item-icon.jpg" alt=""> 
                               kraft 
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="ausdauer.html">
                            <div class="nav-item"> 
                               <img src="images/item-icon.jpg" alt=""> 
                                ausdauer </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="wellness.html">
                            <div class="nav-item">
                              <img src="images/item-icon.jpg" alt="">
                               wellness</div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="extras.html">
                            <div class="nav-item"> 
                              <img src="images/item-icon.jpg" alt="">
                              extras</div>
                        </a>

                </div>
```

I already gave it a try but I am stuck in the  element and how to make the image element inside of it, and this is what I so far tried

```
lib.header_menu = COA
lib.header_menu {
10 = HMENU
10 {
    wrap = <div class="row">|</div>
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <a>|</a>
```

Could you please help me ? so that the menu at the end looks exactly so : 
[image]

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? drop down menu?

Comment: no not a drop down menu .. I just edited my text and added a picture to show you what I am trying to build

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to get to that?

Comment: I am working on a typo3 website .. and the menu must be dynamically generated .. so it needs to be with typoscript generated . I mean the typoscript generates the html code and of course I have already my css style . I just need the typoscript code that generates the same hierarchy.

Comment: Ah I see. It could be useful to include what you wrote above in your question as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[...]
1 = TMENU
1 {
    NO.linkWrap = <div class="nav-item"><img src="images/item-icon.jpg" alt="">|</div>
    NO.ATagBeforeWrap = 1
}
[...]
```

by using linkWrap with ATagBeforeWrap you can tell TYPO3 to wrap the link text first and then wrap the a-tag around that. Not tested, but it should work.